# How to Print Text Directly In XHTML 5

Tags: xhtml

Is there any tag that tells the browser to simply print what is inside the tag, without caring about the syntax of what is inside the tag? I'm trying to print a few unicode characters, but the browser keeps giving errors, even if I paste the character directly inside of a pre tag, without using ampersands.

I'm trying to print © inside of a div tag, but that putting that character inside of a div tag results in an "improperly formatted" error (the page doesn't even show up in Mozilla Firefox, and the sentence with the copyright symbol isn't printed in Microsoft Edge).

The page is being served as application/xhtml+xml.

Here is the code:

```
<footer>©</footer>
```

and here is the error:

```
XML Parsing Error: not well-formed Location: http://programcode.net/ Line Number 19, Column 13:
<footer></footer>
```

------------^

If I do this:

```
<footer><pre>© </pre></footer>
```

then the same error occurs:

```
XML Parsing Error: not well-formed Location: http://programcode.net/ Line Number 19, Column 18:
<footer><pre> </pre></footer>
```

-----------------^

I tried declaring utf-8 and utf-32 (in both the meta tag in the xhtml file, and .htaccess), but the error still occurred.

Comment: Could you share which characters are you trying to show and which is the print are you expecting to get?

Comment: @DMC19 I edited  the question.

Comment: An © symbol shouldn't cause a problem. Exactly, what does the error message say in Firefox?

Comment: Are you declaring utf8 in the head?

Comment: @Rob I tried declaring utf-8 and utf-32 (in both the meta tag in the xhtml file, and .htaccess), but the error still occurred.

Comment: You are not actually changing the encoding of the page by putting a meta tag in the file. My guess is that you have saved the file with another encoding. Load the file into an editor and see that the editor says the character set is.

Answer (score 0):

XHTML is awesome because it uses the XML parser which is extremely strict. When you have an error you *know* you have an error and that you need to fix it. I've seen a person spend three days trying to figure out why Safari wouldn't work but all the other browsers worked fine (he was missing a quote around an element's attribute).

What you need to do is encode HTML entities. There are a few websites that show you the full Unicode ranges and their characters. I recommend using https://unicode-table.com/en/ because it's less intimidating.

Now once you're there you'll want to want to [search for the copyright](https://unicode-table.com/en/search/?q=copyright) symbol.

Next you'll click the obvious symbol and you'll end up on the [copyright page](https://unicode-table.com/en/00A9/).

You're looking for the **HTML-code** (the proper terminology when speaking with other professionals is "numeric HTML entity"). Never use the loose "Entity" (`&copy;`), you want to always use the numeric HTML entity (`&#169;`).

So your code should look like the following:
    ©

XHTML, CSS and JavaScript handle HTML entities a bit differently.

For **JavaScript Entities** you'll need to replace the uppercase 'U' with a lowercase 'u', remove the '+'. Here is an example that you can run from any browser's web developer console:

```
alert('Look at my \u00A9 date!');
```

Note that you *must* have the double zeroes for the copyright symbol (removing them will break the code).

For **CSS Entities** it's a little simpler:

```
h1::after {content: '\00A9'; display: block; float: left;}
```

**Why is this so complex?**

There are eight bits to a byte (one megabit a second is really only 125,000 bytes (125 kilobytes) a second. Some characters can not by represented by a single character in code. There are multiple levels of Unicode (universal character set) but most websites are moving to UTF-8. Some languages (such as Chinese, to the best of my understanding) use a symbol for an entire word (they their "alphabet" is *much* longer). All these characters have to somehow be represented by code (that you do not see). There is a big move to support UTF-8 natively everywhere (especially the web). Pretty much anything above character code 127 should be encoded when using XHTML. It may or it may not work natively and that is a more advanced topic for a different question. Hopefully this will give you enough insight to get a moving and a grooving though.